# NextJS NextRequest Context

Tags: http, next.js, request, http-headers

I would like to understand a behavior in my NextJS application.

For each request a middleware is launched, which looks like this:

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
   request.headers.set('Custom-Header', 'Custom-Value');
   ...
   return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Then a custom route is called (route handler):

```
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
   const customHeaderValue = request.headers.get('Custom-Header');
   console.log(customHeaderValue); // null
}
```

Could you explain to me why I don't have access to the data defined in the middleware in the GET route ?

So I tried to set various values, but nothing works, and from what I understood the NextRequest object is the context of the current request.

Comment: Read this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset Already done and tested their method to set Headers, nothing changes